# Emmet и PhpStorm некорректное форматирование

Tags: html, phpstorm, css

На всякий случай http://habrahabr.ru/post/170565/

```
div.nav>a.button-nav[href=#]{$}*5
```

Всю голову уже сломал, не могу понять, почему emmet разворачивает выхлоп в одну строку всегда.
Нормально работает только с ul>li, всё остальное разворачивается, как правило, в одну строку с кривым форматированием.

Пробовал разворачивать этот же код в Brackets, всё нормально и красиво распахивает.

Кто работает с Emmet, объясните, пожалуйста, где косяк.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос закрыт, на просторах инета [нашёл](http://htmlforum.ru/index.php?showtopic=49263) мануал, как это настраивается.  
Если вдруг картинка по ссылке пропадёт, то действуйте по инструкции ниже:

File -> Settings -> Code Style -> HTML -> (вкладка) Other 
Поля:

- Insert new line before
- Inline elements
- Don`t break if inline content

Настраиваете теги в этих полях, и всё заработает с красивыми отступами.